# Difference on starting activity

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm just curious to find if there is any difference for starting activity between these two types

```
StartActivity (typeof (MainActivity));

StartActivity (new Intent (this,typeof (MainActivity)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the first as a shortcut for the second.

If you dont want to share any data to the new activity you can call the first.

In other cases you may want to pass an Id or any other data to use in the target activity through a `Bundle` with the `PutExtra` methods of the Intent.

Comment: Second one has any property to check if activity is already opened?

Comment: As far as i know, there's no variable or method to check against, although it seems to be possible writing some code. But if your concerned about not launching several instances of the same activity, try looking for activities' "launchMode", specially for "singleTask" and "singleTop".

See: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en